# How do you test if something is older than 3 months?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been having some trouble to select the rows of my table which has a date of 3 months prior of today. I tried using `DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)` in my where clause, but no luck. How do I check in SQL Server if a item is older than 3 months?

```
  UPDATE[TCTdb].[dbo].[Stock]
     SET[Warehouse] = 'old'
   WHERE [ManufacturedDate] <= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Comment: is it actual months or is it 90 days?  would it be 5/3 or older right?

Comment: Definitely 3 months. not 90 days

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Your syntax appears to be wrong.

That should be

```
UPDATE[TCTdb].[dbo].[Stock]
    SET[Warehouse] = 'old'
WHERE [ManufacturedDate] <= DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: ++1 This format will also work best with any indexing you may have on the ManufacturedDate field

Answer (score 9):

Use [`dateadd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

```
update [TCTdb].[dbo].[Stock]
set [WareHouse] = 'old'
where [ManufacturedDate] < dateadd(month,-3,getdate())
```

I suggest [`dateadd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) over [`datediff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) because I think you're going to get unexpected results using [`datediff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) with the [`month`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) datepart.

Consider that the following statements both return `3`:

```
select datediff(month, '1/1/2011','4/1/2011')
select datediff(month, '1/1/2011','4/30/2011')
```

Either works in this particular case... Just keep that behavior in mind.

Comment: +1 for linking to the DATEADD article on MSDN so I could find out what other values besides "month" are valid for the first argument.

Answer (score 3):

The DATEDIFF function should be helpful to you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

```
UPDATE[TCTdb].[dbo].[Stock]
    SET[Warehouse] = 'old'
    WHERE DATEDIFF(month, [ManufacturedDate], GETDATE()) > 3
```

Comment: -1 DATEDIFF is wrong. 01 Jan to 30 Apr is 3 months difference for example @marc_s: it's actually wrong

Comment: He is looking for 3 months, not 90 days.   01 Jan to 30 Apr is 3 months.  How many months would you say it is?

Comment: @hspain: usign DATEADD with -3 months isn't 90 days. I subtracts 3 calendar months. If I wanted stuff older then 3 months on 30 April, I'd expect a cut off of 30 January. A business user would see it that way too:

Answer (score 1):

try out DATEDIFF:

```
SELECT 
    case 
        when DATEDIFF(month, '2005-12-31' , '2006-04-01 ') > 3
        then 'yes'

        else 'no'

    end
```

Hope that helps,

John

Comment: DATEDIFF is wrong. 01 Jan to 30 Apr is 3 months difference for example -1