# How to get users who are not active for the past 6 months

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field `transaction_date` which is varchar2, I want to make a search on that field and get user_id of that user who is not active for the past 6 months

I tried with below query but its not giving correct answer, my query is:

```
select distinct(user_id) 
from DAILYBOOKINGREPORT2 
where TRANSACTION_DATE  NOT BETWEEN to_date('31-MAY-2017') AND to_date('31-DEC-2016');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you test if something is older than 3 months?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931619/how-do-you-test-if-something-is-older-than-3-months)

Comment: What should happen if a user has *never* been active?

Comment: if that user records are not found in past 6 months records

Comment: Check with AddMonth function of oracle

Comment: @ReeceYoung Not a duplicate - that question is for SQL Server and this is for Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to find those users where the maximum transaction date was more than 6 months ago:

```
SELECT   user_id
FROM     DAILYBOOKINGREPORT2
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   MAX( TRANSACTION_DATE ) < ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -6 );
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to make use of the DATEADD function

```
SELECT 
       DISTINCT(user_id) 
 FROM `DAILYBOOKINGREPORT2` 
WHERE `TRANSACTION_DATE` <= DATEADD(mm, -6, GETDATE())
```

More information: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Comment: `DATEADD` is not an Oracle function and backticks are not valid Oracle syntax.